# Django dropdown [onChange] box with selected values but can't get the selected value

Tags: javascript, html, django, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown selection of titles that upon selection of specific title, an action (should) run.

What I have:

**form.py**

```
class CronForm(forms.Form): 
    title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=GlobalFID.objects.all().order_by('-title_date'), widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'change_title()'}))
```

view.py [title_change_view ]

```
my_form = CronForm() #initial=data
return render(request, 'research/title_result.html',{"my_form":my_form})
```

**html**

```
    <form method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ my_form }}
    </form>
```

**and on the js side:**

```
function change_title()
{ 
    var murl= "{% url 'title_change_view' %}"; 
    window.location = murl; 
}
```

my goal is to have the SELECTED title from {{my_form}} in the view title_change_view. While the redirection works, I can't get the selected value.

Strategies I considered/tried:

1. In the title_change_view I added `if request.method == 'POST':` but it's not a post (so it overlook it) so I can't read the form.
2. `var murl= "{% url 'title_change_view' %}";`  to add additional parameter `?title=[SELCTED_VALUE]` but couldn't figure out how to add the SELECTED title into murl or into the change_title() fuction.

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the right approach at all. Redirecting the browser will never submit any data. You need to actually post it; in your case, you can do it by simply submitting the form.

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="{% url 'title_change_view' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ my_form }}
</form>
```

...

```
function change_title() { 
    document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
}
```